# Как сохранить объект с полем Image(JavaFX) в файл?

Tags: java, изображения, javafx, serializable

есть класс

```
public class Portret implements Serializable{
    private Image img;

    public Image getImg(){
        if(img!=null)return img;
        else img = new Image("...");
        return img;
    }
    public void setImg(Image im){
        img=im;
    }
}
```

его нужно сохранить в файл, но класс Image (JavaFX) не реализует интерфейс Serializable, соответственно при попытке сохранить его в файл выдает ошибку "NotSerializableException" из-за присутствия поля Image img.
Решил объявить поле как "transient" но нужно в каком-то виде сохранить изображение в самом экземпляре класса.
Подскажите как можно обойти это ограничение, или же во что можно конвертировать изображение(с целью его последующего восстановления) в пределах экземпляра класса чтобы Java позволила осуществить запись объекта в файл?

Comment: Если кто знает то можно просто подсказать как проще всего сконвертировать Image в массив байтов и обратно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел, самое простое решение из тех что накопал.
Конвертирует изображение в массив int (чтобы поддавался сериализации) и обратно.

```
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelReader;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelWriter;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class SerializableImage implements Serializable {
    private int width, height;
    private int[][] data;

    public SerializableImage() {}

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        width = ((int) image.getWidth());
        height = ((int) image.getHeight());
        data = new int[width][height];

        PixelReader r = image.getPixelReader();
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                data[i][j] = r.getArgb(i, j);
            }
        }

    }

    public Image getImage() {
        WritableImage img = new WritableImage(width, height);

        PixelWriter w = img.getPixelWriter();
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                w.setArgb(i, j, data[i][j]);
            }
        }

        return img;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно пойти разными путями как то:
Если допускается сохранить нарисованное в FX изображение на диск и  сериализованье объекта с ссылкой на сохраненное изображение то короткий путь для сохранения изображения такой:

```
ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(img, null), "png", new File("out.png"));
```

Можно к примеру получить массив и сохранять уже его...как пример такая стратегия:

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) (img.getWidth()*img.getHeight())];
    i.getPixelReader().getPixels(0, 0, img.getWidth(),img.getWidth(),PixelFormat.getByteRgbInstance(), buffer, img.getWidth());
```

В общем если немного пофантазировать то найдутся еще много варианты.

UPD: Как создать изображение из массива(Пример!читайте документацию):

```
    byte[] buffer1 = /** **/;
    Canvas c = new Canvas();
    GraphicsContext gc = c.getGraphicsContext2D();
    gc.getPixelWriter().setPixels(0, 0, 10, 10,  PixelFormat.getByteRgbInstance(), buffer , 10, 0);
```

Comment: Во внешний файл не нужно записывать отдельно изображение, оно не должно покидать пределов объекта в котором находится в виде поля, поэтому и нужно его превратить в массив байтов.